# Нормы произношения звука W

Tags: транскрипция

В русском языке английский звук W пишут то как В, то как У (любая гласная). А есть ли какая-то норма? Например, мы знаем доктора Ватсона, но при этом ДНК открыли Уотсон и Крик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, как вообще объяснить эти тонкости, не выходя за рамки собственно русского языка...

Сочетания WA, WO, WE, WI, WU  в современных английских именах собственных обычно передаются через УО, ВО, ВЕ, ВИ, ВУ соответственно. Впрочем, последующий звук может сказываться и на передаче самого сочетания - в зависимости от особенностей английской фонетики. Другими словами, сейчас русское написание таких имен старается максимально передать английскую фонетику. Звук W в общем-то вполне адекватно передаётся русским звуком В, но перед О как "У", что объясняется не столько английским, сколько русским произношением этого сочетания. (Я так понимаю, что О в русском имеет явный призвук У, и для передачи английского сочетания ту дифтонгоидность следует усилить.)

Ранее обычно старались быть ближе к написанию, отсюда и разночтения.